# Checking whether an object exists in StructureMap container

Tags: nhibernate, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm using StructureMap to handle the creation of NHibernate's 
ISessionFactory and ISession. I've scoped ISessionFactory as a 
singleton so that it's only created once for my web app and I've 
scoped ISession as a hybrid so that it will only be opened once per 
web request.

I want to make sure that at the end of each web request, I properly 
dispose of ISession if it was created for that web request. I figured 
I could put some code in my Application_EndRequest routine to first 
check if an ISession was created, and if so, call ISession.Dispose.

My current workaround is to just open up an ISession on 
Application_BeginRequest then dispose of it on Application_EndRequest, 
but that seems somewhat wasteful in that static file requests for 
images and css files and whatnot will create an ISession without ever 
using it. I know that the overall performance hit is negligable since 
ISessions are very lightweight, but it's getting annoying seeing all 
those ISessions being created inside NHProf.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to StructureMap 2.6.1, I ended up using the new ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects() function to achieve what I wanted.